# Check Constraint: Foreign Key type constraint only on first write

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a table serving as a log of calculations. Upon entering data, I would like to check if the data entered in some columns exists in another table. In this other table, the data is in fact the primary key, so I could create a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint - however, I only want the consistency with this "foreign key" to be checked once for each row after newly inserting it, but never again. I do not want to create an actual parent-child relationship of these tables, as the 'child' should keep records regardless of changes to the 'parent'.

I have attempted to implement this using a `CHECK` constraint, e.g.:

```
CONSTRAINT CSTR_CALCLOG1 CHECK (USERID in(select USERID from USER_TABLE))
```

Resulting in the error:

```
ORA-02251: subquery not allowed here
```

It seems that `check constraints` are fairly limited as described here, and therefore not the right tool for the job:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_check_constraint.htm

How can this be achieved?

Comment: an on insert trigger?

Comment: "...only to be checked when first writing to the table..." - Do you mean 1) on the first inserted row only, 2) while inserting the first transaction, but not after that, or 3) after inserting the main batch of rows, but never again?

Comment: @TheImpaler Sorry for the ambiguity. I mean once for each row after newly inserting it, but never again. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @BryanDellinger Perhaps? I understand that using a BEFORE insert trigger I could carry out the check before a new line is inserted. This sounds like what I need. It seems like constraints are not the right tool for this, although they almost seem to fit the bill.

Comment: @marcus_a "Foreign Key Contraints" (emphasis in constraints) restrict behavior of both related tables, not just the child table The parent table may not delete or update the referenced keys, and the child table may not insert or update rows. Having said that, the constraint is only checked on row changes: that means it's checked on `INSERT` and `UPDATE` on the child table row, and it's checked on the `UPDATE` and `DELETE` of the parent row. Apart from these data changes, the FK is not checked at all.